# Where do I find the default Ambiance theme?

Tags: themes, ambiance

Where can I find the source code for the default GTK theme for Ubuntu? My Google-fu has failed me and I'm not finding the code for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get it from the source package of the light-themes using:

`sudo apt-get source light-themes`